# Reducer may not dispatch actions

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I'm seeing a lot of "Reducer may not dispatch actions" in my error logs. We have a large redux/redux-thunk app. I've looked through our reducers, and none of them have dispatches in them. They are all synchronous functions that just return new state. No side effects. We do however dispatch actions with redux-thunk, and the errors we have seem to indicate that we only hit this error when dispatching new actions in a thunk.

I've found these two github threads, which I believe are related, but it appears to largely be a big back and forth with no resolution.

- https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/122
- https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2753

> ```
> "redux": "3.7.2",
> "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
> ```

I'd like to know, how I can fix this issue, or at least how I can gather more data on this. Most of the error stacks I have are largely from our last middleware calling `next(action);`. From our error logs I've only found instances of this issue with thunks.

Comment: Best things that would help are:  1) a smaller project that reproduces the issue, and 2) complete stack traces for the errors.  If you can come up with either of those, please comment in the Redux issue thread.

Comment: Thanks @markerikson I'll see what I can do, I'll have to obfuscate our stacks somehow.